# Laravel Append value in paginated result

Tags: laravel, append

I am trying to generate a result in laravel where I can add one value in a result.
For example I am using this query:

```
  $variable = model::where('did', '=', $did)->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$name}%")->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(6);
```

And this is generating result:

```
total: 23,
per_page: 6,
current_page: 3,
last_page: 4,
next_page_url: "url/api/v1/model?did=b2d5c031ce301144&name=&page=4",
prev_page_url: "url/api/v1/model?did=b2d5c031ce301144&name=&page=2",
from: 13,
to: 18,
data: [
{
number: "9739693089",
message: "Message from Nilay 21",
type: "Received",
did: "b2d5c031ce301144",
},
 .....
```

I want to add one more column like full name in this result where I need to check if number is ... then full name should add value x or nothing. I have tried append in model but I can't check and add value.

Comment: You probably have to use `Laravel Accessors`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor
With accessor you can define something like `computed` fields. 
You can define a method in your Model like : 
`public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}`

With that, every time you call the `$model->full_name` attribute, it will do all the magic inside this method. Inside this method  you can access any model properties, write any logic and so on ;)

Comment: Note that accessors will not be displayed in your collection or even single result. This column is not existing and don't have to exist, but in your views or anywhere you have to reach for it, you just call this attribute on specific model instance and get all the magic from inside, but inside you can access and modify any Model instance attributes, so it looks one more time that you need to use them

Answer (score -1):

The best way, as it has already been suggested would be to use an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor).

So, you could have the following method defined in your model.

```php
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->number ? 'fullname' : ''; 
}
```

... and then you would be able to access it using

```php
$model->fullName;
```

If you can't do that, for whatever reason, here's an alternative.
Since paginated results are essentially a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections), you could map over it and add the field you need.

```php
$variable = Model::where('did', '=', $did)
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$name}%")
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(6)
    ->map(function($model) {
        // You can do your check here
        // for example if($model->number) {} 
        $model->fullName = 'test';

        return $model;
    });
```

Comment: Every item becomes null with this method strange enough

Comment: inside the map function, you have to return the $model.
i.e. `
$model->fullName = 'test';
return $model;
`